# How can I flash zip in recovery from an app in android?

Tags: java, android, root, recovery

I am trying to build an ota updater app which will reboot your device into recovery and flash a zip located in /sdcard/updater/update.zip.

I saw this solution: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8720087/3057931)

So here is my current code:

```
  Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = null;
    String SDCARD = "/sdcard/updater/update.zip";
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    try{
        p = run.exec("su");
        out = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
       // out.writeBytes("echo 'install_zip(\""+ SDCARD+"\");'" +" > /cache/recovery/extendedcommand\n");
        out.writeBytes("adb shell");
        out.writeBytes("echo 'install_zip(\""+SDCARD+"\");' > /cache/recovery/extendedcommand");
        out.writeBytes("reboot recovery\n"); // testing
        out.flush();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("FLASH", "Unable to reboot into recovery mode:", e);
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

But for me it just reboot to recovery and does nothing.
Please help.

I'm using TWRP latest version.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page: http://www.teamw.in/OpenRecoveryScript

you need to change your

```
/cache/recovery/extendedcommand
```

to

```
/cache/recovery/openrecoveryscript
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the [android.os.RecoverySystem.installPackage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RecoverySystem#installPackage(android.content.Context,%20java.io.File)) function does that.